# Does the openssl command line do key strengthening?

Tags: cryptography, openssl

If I run the openssl command line in hmac mode (as below), is the key used for the hmac used directly or is it hashed before using it as the key?

```
echo "foo" | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary -hmac "test" | openssl base64
```

Similarly, when encrypting a file with openssl (as below)is the pass phrase hashed with the salt? (If so how is it done? A pointer to the right source file would be even better.)

```
openssl enc -salt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hmac option does not use salting or hashing; it just uses the passphrase directly as the key. See `apps/dgst.c` in the source distribution:

```
            else if (!strcmp(*argv,"-hmac"))
                    {
                    if (--argc < 1)
                            break;
                    hmac_key=*++argv;
                    }
    ...

    if (hmac_key)
            {
            sigkey = EVP_PKEY_new_mac_key(EVP_PKEY_HMAC, e,
                                    (unsigned char *)hmac_key, -1);
            if (!sigkey)
                    goto end;
            }
```

The `enc` command does seem to use some form of salting, at least in some cases. The relevant source file is `apps/enc.c`, but seems to come with some caveats:

```
            /* Note that str is NULL if a key was passed on the command
             * line, so we get no salt in that case. Is this a bug?
             */
            if (str != NULL)
                    {
                    /* Salt handling: if encrypting generate a salt and
                     * write to output BIO. If decrypting read salt from
                     * input BIO.
                     */
```

It then uses the function `EVP_BytesToKey` (in `crypto/evp/evp_key.c`) to generate a random key. This function seems to be a non-standard algorithm, which looked perhaps plausibly OK at a very brief glance but I couldn't attest to it beyond that.

Source snippets and comments are all from the OpenSSL 1.0.0 release.

Comment: Thank you! I think I understand it fully now.

Also I found the doc to that function here: http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_BytesToKey.html

Comment: EVP_BytesToKey is quite close to PBKDF1.

Comment: Note that, regarding the enc command, using -k or -kfile does the salting, using -K does not do salting. In the source, -k and -kfile populate str, whereas -K populates hkey.